# Modal popup from livepipe

Tags: javascript, popup

I need to use the "modal window" of livepipe(a prototype plugin) to make a popup window in my application.

The demo of this in its website shows `triggering` the popup via clicking a `<a>` tag.

Now I need to make the page so that it will automatically throw the popup when the page is loaded, I am quite green on javascript, could anyone shed some light on how to do so?

I will post the script for how to do it via `<a>` tag  below:

```
<body>
<div id = "zhao" >
<iframe src='http://www.netease.com' width='500px' height='500'></iframe>
</div>
<a id="modal" href="#zhao">Modal Window</a>
</body>    

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://livepipe.net/javascripts/all.js?1256410438'></script> 

<script type= 'text/javascript'>
//Modal Window 
document.observe('dom:loaded',function(){ 

var modal = new Control.Modal($('modal'),{  
    overlayOpacity: 0.75,  
    className: 'modal',  
    fade: true  
});  

});
</script>
```

I suppose I need to somehow mock the `<a>` and its href atribute via javascript, right?  What is the most difficult to me is that how could I mockup the action of "click the link" via javascript, so that I can trigger the action when page is loaded.

Comment: You think you need to mock what?

Comment: the click action of the <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the popup when the page loads, why don't you just call .open() on your `modal` object? You don't have to mock the action of a click on the `<a>`

```
<script type= 'text/javascript'>
//Modal Window 
document.observe('dom:loaded',function(){ 

var modal = new Control.Modal($('modal'),{  
    overlayOpacity: 0.75,  
    className: 'modal',  
    fade: true  
});  

modal.open();

});
</script>
```

API: http://livepipe.net/control/window